# Filter geolocation in flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I have a series of geolocation and I need to get the geolocation inside a 1 mile radius. Is there any way I can do this with flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire) package to do this it's not a native functionality in flutter or dart.

Comment: Oh thanks, I've looked at other packages but they didn't have the radius option or the option wasn't obvious for me. This looks promising, I'll give it a try. Thank you!